# Is it possible to create an api for community users to connect to our salesforce org

Tags: apex

Is it possible to create an api like google or facebook for our community users to use on their websites using the rest api.

I did have an idea around creating connected apps on a user by user basis.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using jwt.  We just did this for one of our clients. It is the only way we found to bring community users into the org without a browser intermediating authorization.

http://doingpoorly.blogspot.com/2014/11/jwt-bearer-token-flow-can-be-used-for.html